# Check if mining World of Warcraft

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

How would I check if the player is mining in World of Warcraft and then cast a mount once mining is complete?

Comment: Pretty sure a regular WoW addon can't do this - specifically, to prevent botting.

Comment: I don't play WoW but it seems likely that this sort of scripted action would be considered abusive and would likely go against the terms.  I.E.  This is botting.

Comment: @MattBall, no it can, but withing limitations. Out-of-combat spellcasting still can be automated and only requires "hardware event" - i.e. keypress.

Answer (score 6):

To figure out if a character is mining, listen to the [UNIT_SPELLCAST_START](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/events/UNIT_SPELLCAST_START) and `UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED`/`UNIT_SPELLCAST_FAILED` events. Check that `unitID == player` and `spellID == miningSpellId` (there are several, one for each rank, so you might want to consider using the spell name instead).

However, you cannot automatically cast a mount once your mining is finished, as mining is initialized by clicking a world object (i.e. the mining node) which is out of reach for addons. You could use a SecureActionButtonTemplate button to grab your hardware event and cast a mount, but linking that to the action of mining should be out of scope.